# How do I turn off automatic stylesheet/javascript generation on Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript, sass

I've got a Rails 3.1 project that I'm working on, but I don't want `controller_name.css.sass` and `controller_name.js.coffee` to be generated each time I run `rails generate controller controller_name`. I could *swear* I've seen the setting somewhere on the internet, but I can't find it now for the life of me. What is it?

Keep in mind that I'm still wanting to use the Asset Pipeline and the CoffeeScript/Sass integration, but I'm organizing those files in my own way.

I'm pretty sure the answer is a command line argument, but bonus points for turning it off with a generator setting or a hidden file or something.

**EDIT**: I've found the command line flag for it.

```
rails generate controller controller_name --assets=false
```

Or something of the like (that line actually errors out, but it also doesn't generate the assets). The API [here](http://rdoc.info/github/rails/rails/master/Rails/Generators) shows `:assets => true` as a default option. How do I change that to false and have it always be false every time I generate a controller?

Comment: if you add `-h` to the end of a rails command it'll give you the help file: `rails g controller -h`

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Add these lines to `application.rb`:

```
config.generators.stylesheets = false
config.generators.javascripts = false
```

Comment: That is so awesome. I was able to verify that it works. Thanks!

Comment: This one-liner does the same `config.generators.assets = false`

Comment: Nice permanent solution. Probably only needs to go into `development.rb` not `application.rb` since it only applies to development environment.

Comment: summarizing, `environments/development.rb`, `config.generators.assets = false` and for no helpers, `config.generators.helper = false`

Answer (score 21):

New syntax is `rails generate controller Resources --no-assets`.

Don't forget you can also use `g` in place of `generate`. And you can skip the creation of a controller helper using the `--no-helper` flag.

Answer (score 10):

For just one time, use:

```
rails generate controller controller_name --no-assets
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @RomanC Uh, what? As far as I can tell, it does provide an answer to the question. It says how to turn off automatic asset generation, albeit just for one run of the command.

Answer (score 7):

An update on @Dmitry Maksimov's answer for Rails 4.2. You can disable generation of controller-specific asset files by default with the following in your `config/application.rb` file (source: [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.0/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets)):

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.assets false
end
```

Answer (score 1):

My whole options in the application.rb file:

```
config.generators do |g|
    g.stylesheets = false
    g.javascripts = false
    g.test_framework  :rspec, fixture: false
    g.template_engine :haml
    g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, dir: 'spec/factories'
end
```