# How to disable the generator of assets on rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Every time I create a controller, rails generate a controler_name.js and a controller_name.css file on app/assets folder. I already disable the config.assets.enabled param on application.rb but this not solve my problem.
How can I disable the generator for those files when creating controller ?

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can pass `--skip-assets` to your command to prevent these files from being created:

```
rails g controller foo --skip-assets
```

If you want something more permanent, you can turn it off altogether. Add this to `config/application.rb` (from [How do I turn off automatic stylesheet/javascript generation on Rails 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366273/how-do-i-turn-off-automatic-stylesheet-javascript-generation-on-rails-3-1))

```
config.generators.stylesheets = false
config.generators.javascripts = false
```

Comment: Alternatively:  ```config.generators.assets = false```

Comment: I use rails 5 and it warn `Expected string default value for '--template-engine'; got false (boolean)` but replace `false` with `nil` works fine - silently disable.

Comment: Thanks @oklas, I had the same challenge in Rails-5+